# How to insert multiple images inline body of Email using C#

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

I am trying insert images in the body(inline) of the Email, and i am able to insert the image.

But for multiple images i am facing tough time here.

```
emailMessage.Body = "<div style=\"font-family:Arial\">This is an INLINE attachment:<br /><br /><img src=\"\\shared folder\image 1.png" alt=\"\"><br /><br />Thanks for downloading this example.</br><img src=\"\\shared folder\image 2.png" alt=\"\"> </br>
```

Body will look like the above. to do this i am trying to do the following.

1. scan the text for
2. get the value in the src attribute
   3.put each of those values in a string list
   4.loop through the list and in the loop, and want to place the below code which is working for a single image.

can any body suggest how to achieve this in functionality using C# syntax. 
Sample email message body like this :

```
                    emailMessage.Body = "<div style=\"font-family:Arial\">This is an INLINE attachment:<br /><br /><img src=\"\\shared folder\image 1.png" alt=\"\"><br /><br />Thanks for downloading this example.</br><img src=\"\\shared folder\image 2.png" alt=\"\"> </br>;
                    //string strRegex = "/src=([^\\"]+)/";
                    //Regex srcRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
                    string[] immageArray = Regex.Split(emailMessage.Body, "<img src=");


                    //string[] immageArray = Regex.Match(emailMessage.Body, srcRegex,RegexOptions.None,Timesp);
                    foreach(string imgLine in immageArray)
                    {
                        attachmentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + imgLine;
                        // generate the contentID string using the datetime
                         contentID = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath).Replace(".", "") + "@zofm";
                         // create the INLINE attachment
                         Attachment inline = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
                         inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                         inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
                         inline.ContentId = contentID;
                         inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
                         inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath);
                         emailMessage.Attachments.Add(inline);

                         // replace the tag with the correct content ID
                         emailMessage.Body = emailMessage.Body.Replace("@@IMAGE@@", "cid:" + contentID);
                    }
```

But i am not able to fetch the image path from the emailMessage.Body , can any body correct this?
thank you.

Comment: Dear experts, any regularexpression to fetch alll imagage names from src attribute to list please?